# WebGL Camera and Lighting Setting

Tags: webgl

May I have any help regarding the WebGL.

1. Where is the origin position (default) without set any position and rotation of camera and lighting source?
2. If we set the position and rotation of camera, it will affect the object?

Comment: see [http://webglfundamentals.org](http://webglfundamentals.org)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all OpenGL, there is no real "camera." The view is from the origin (0,0,0) looking in the positive Z direction.

The way you move your "camera" is to translate all objects in the scene so that your camera location is back at the origin. For example, if your camera is at (0,10,0), you move all objects by (0,-10,0). The same goes for rotations.

A good resource on this is here:
http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help... When u change the position of 'camera', it will affect all the thing in canvas?